# Invalid component tried calling function [get] with arguments [v.params], markup://namespace:lightningComponent [18:624;a]

Tags: lightning-aura-components, customer-community

This problem occurred when my Lightning Component embedded in Community. The line `"component.get('v.param')"` only works for the first time after the page has loaded. From the every second time it works no more, while the same code in pure Lightning environment works well. This can be reproduced easily.

I caught the error and it shows as below:

```
action: null

data:null

handled:false

id:"1ad79aa6-3598-4a7d-bab1-9f98c1c44b98"

message:"Invalid component tried calling function [get] with arguments [v.param], markup://namespace:MyLightningComponent [6:247;a]"

name:"AuraError"

o:"InvalidComponent markup://namespace:MyLightningComponent {6:247;a}"

reported:false

severity:"QUIET"
```

This issue has blocked my development in Community. Hope to be answered soon.

Comment: maybe you have tried getting the "param" in controller which is not declared in aura:attribute. Please declare the "param" in an aura:attribute
<aura:attribute name="param" type="" />
Hope this helps, if not if you can post your code we can provide more insight.

Comment: Thanks for your help! But I've declared the param in the component. The same code in Lightning did running well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Invalid component" errors means the component has been destroyed but you're still trying to interact with it. So in this case when you call `component.get('v.param')`, whatever `component` references has already been destroyed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! But why the same code in Lightning did running well. I found that the component object in Community is not the same with that in Lightning. I want to know why the time it is destroyed is different with that in Lightning. All I did is I embedded a component in a community page I created. And I use navigateToURL event navigating to the page I created and I need to transfer some parameters. Is there any way for me to resolve this problem?

Comment: @S.Wayne Are you getting a reference to the `component` object before firing the `navigateToURL` event? If so, the navigate event probably destroys and current components and recreates them on the new page you've navigated to. This would cause the InvalidComponent error, and I would suggest getting a fresh reference to the component you care about after the navigate event.

Comment: Yes, I can only reference to the component for the first time, so I guess the component has been destroyed for the second time I try to reference it. So how could I get a fresh reference after the navigate event?

Comment: Hard to say without knowing your actual code. If you're responding to some event, the handler method will have the source component as the first parameter. If you want to grab a different component in the markup you can add `aura:id="foo"` to the component you care about and then in your javascript do a `component.find("foo")` and get the `param` attribute off what that returns.

Comment: I add some logic by component.isValid() to check if the component is valid before I get the parameter from it. It's magical that the code executed for the second time and the component is valid and I can get the parameters then. Thanks for your help!